# How upload large JSON object in javascript with form data?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, large-data

I'm trying to upload a very large object that contains several arrays within which are more arrays. I tried to upload using FormData but the upload is received as a string, like so:

Upload code:

```
formData.append('large_json', largObj);
```

As received on server:

```
{ "bob" : "[[Object object], [Object object]]" }
```

The string may be 15 million characters long. What are my options to get this to the server?

If it helps, I'm running an express server.

Comment: Have you looked into https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer ? And for the client side, something like this: http://www.resumablejs.com/

Comment: What is `largObj`? Is it in JSON object form or is it a string representation? How are you printing the object/viewing the received file on the server?

Comment: @WillS largObj, in my example above, a json object. The data is printed via console.log on the server. However, if the json object is stringify'd before submitting, then the site crashes due to the String value being too large.

Comment: If it is the site that is crashing, can you post any code related to handling the file upload (like the Express handler)? It shouldn't be a problem to upload a 15 million character file (15~60 MB in UTF-8).

Also, you might want to try something like what @TennysonH suggested to handle form uploads. [node-formidable](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable) seems like another option worth considering as well.

Comment: @WillS I'm not sending it as a file. It is a String. The receiving end of the code should not be the problem. It's a simple console.log(req.body.key).

Answer (score 1):

I think you are sending the object to the server, not the info in it.

Did you already try to transform your `object` to `JSON`?

```
formData.append('large_json', JSON.stringify(largObj));
```

Comment: I've tried both converting the object to String and also sending it as an object using formData.append. However, formData.append converts the json to a string anyways, but it doesn't fully convert child elements and simply represents them as "[Object object]". If I explicitly stringify the largeObj before submitting, the result crashes while sending due to the String value being too large ~15M chars in length.